# How to set set hadoop.security.credential.provider.path with the jceks file path from the Oozie- coordinator.xml

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a necessity to set hadoop.security.credential.provider.path with the jceks file path from the Oozie-  coordinator.xml. Note: I'm not interested in setting this core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the jceks file from workflow to authenticate.

e.g. in sqoop action -

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.security.credential.provider.path</name>
<value>${jceks_file}</value>
</property>
```